Almost orthogonal operators after a relative scaling
If two positive operators $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ with unit $\ell_1$ norm are almost orthogonal: $\parallel Q_1 - Q_2 \parallel_1 \geq 2 -\epsilon$, then what can we say about the operators $Q_1$ and $c Q_2$, where $c\geq 0$ is an arbitrary scalar? More precisely, do we have $\parallel Q_1 - c Q_2 \parallel_1 \geq 1 + c - f(\epsilon)$, where $\lim_ {\epsilon\to 0}f(\epsilon)=0$?
